# Multiples functions on customize_register?

Tags: functions

For a better organization of my theme's functions.php, i would like to know if it's possible to add multiples functions with add_action on customize_register ?
Like this for exemple :

```
function banana_customize($wp_customize) {
///// Content of function }
add_action('customize_register','banana_customize')

function coconut_customize($wp_customize) {
///// Content of function }
add_action('customize_register','coconut_customize')
```

If i do this, i have an error and page won't load.

**If this is not possible**, could you tell me how to combine functions like so :

```
function banana_customize($wp_customize) {
///// Content of function }

function coconut_customize($wp_customize) {
///// Content of function }

" function combined_functions = banana_customize + coconut_customize "

add_action('customize_register','combined_functions')
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you can add as many hooks to the same action as you like. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: You could always just make `function combined_functions($wp_customize) { banana_customize($wp_customize); coconut_customize($wp_customize); }` to combine them. But I think it would be more interesting to solve the error, as something strange is going on here.